Start X-axis from custom timestamp instead of 00:00:00 in lightningcharts js
I have a requirement where I have to show the old recorded data with timestamp. Since the x axis always starts from 00:00:00. Is there a way to start it from any time lets say 06:23:20 and then continue from here.
Below is what my current code:
const TIME_DOMAIN = 10 * 1000;
axisX .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Time) .setInterval({ start: -TIME_DOMAIN, end: 0, stopAxisAfter: false }) .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive);
So it starts from -10 seconds to 0 and then continues on.
I tried adding this:
axisX .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Time) .setInterval({ start: 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000, end: 13 * 60*60*1000, stopAxisAfter: false }) .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive);
But the axis just stops moving even with stopAxisAfter: false. Screenshots describes what's happening. I am getting the axes values but it should move tick per tick i.e, 1 second but it shows entire range in the pane. And If I doubleclick, it start moving from 00:00:00.
How do I achieve this functionality?

I tried providing different setIntervals values to start and after keys but it just doesn't work.
I want the X axis to start from custom timestamp let's say 06:20:00, and next tick should be 06:20:01 - 06:20:02 ..... and so on. But unable to achieve.
